# Jquery - check column checkboxes then do something with those rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I've been trying to find a good match to my question, but nothing really concrete.  I'm still learning and don't know exactly what I'm missing.

So my code can be found here: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ea35w1nj/3/)

This is a simplified version of what I'm working with. In the final version, I will upload a csv file to the html table you see there (id="dvCSV").  Upon uploading, the table will look like it is shown (with added dropdowns and a column of checkboxes).  The checkboxes come "pre-chcecked" when I generate them but what I want is the user to be able to turn "off" the rows that I do not want to calculate on.

I'll run you through the process:
This function reads the columns that the user designates. I don't know which column they will upload the data into.

```
function CheckLocations() {
//Checks the uploaded data for the locations of the Lat/Lon Data based on user dropdowns
colLocs[0] = ($('#Value_0 :selected').text());
colLocs[1] = ($('#Value_1 :selected').text());
colLocs[2] = ($('#Value_2 :selected').text());
colLocs[3] = ($('#Value_3 :selected').text());
LatColumn = colLocs.indexOf("Lat");
LongColumn = colLocs.indexOf("Long");
}

function AllTheSame(array) { //if they do not designate the checkboxes, I prompt them to
var first = array[0];
return array.every(function (element) {
    return element === first;
});
}
```

This function takes all of the data in the designated columns and places them into an array for calculation.

```
function data2Array() {
//gets the lat and long data from the assigned columns and transfers them to an array for calculation

$("#dvCSV tr td:nth-child(" + (LatColumn + 1) + ")").each(function () {
    var tdNode = $("<td/>");
    tdNode.html(this.innerHTML);
    LatData.push(tdNode.text());
});
LatData.splice(0, 2);
LatData.unshift(1, 1);

$("#dvCSV tr td:nth-child(" + (LongColumn + 1) + ")").each(function () {
    var tdNode = $("<td/>");
    tdNode.html(this.innerHTML);
    LongData.push(tdNode.text());
});
LongData.splice(0, 2); //these two lines remove the first two items then replace them with 0
LongData.unshift(1, 1);
}
```

The first of these functions removes the checkbox column after calculations are done then new calculated columns are appended at the end. The second one was my attempt to read the checkboxes into an array. Ideally I'd want an array of values true or false, then do the calculations and return the calculated values back to the dvCSV table.  For the td's where no calculation was performed, the cell would be empty.

```
function removeChecks() {
$("#dvCSV th:last-child, #dvCSV td:last-child").remove();
}

function makeCheckArray() {
var searchIDs = $("#dvCSV tbody td:last()     input:checkbox:checked").map(function () {
    return $(this).val();
}).get();
alert(searchIDs);
}
```

Hopefully I made the problem clear. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a class when your table is generated into the tr element. Then create an on change method for your checkboxes. Read more here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Also if you cannot get the inserted rows id's from your table then start a counter outside of your js like this

counter = 0;

Then inside of your loop add counter++

SO..

```
<tr class="row-1">
<td>
</td>
</tr>
```

Then add this snippet outside all of your other JS

```
$( "tr" ).on( "change",  function() {

//do something
$(this+'.row-'+(counter)).hide();

});
```

This should get you headed in the right direction.

Comment: Will hiding the rows make them "not visible' for exporting later on?

Comment: If they are not visible on the screen then they will not be able to be printed.